# trying to make a persistent usb for parrot security 4.5.1

Tags: parrotsec

I have been trying to make a persistent usb for parrot security os 4.5.1
apparently the youtube tutorial i have been using is outdated (linked below) if anybody could tell me what i'm doing wrong here that would be great, i'd love to get this linux distro up and running and start learning

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8EQfn3KbFMs
(the video at the time of this posting is 8 months old)

Answer (score 0):

I have `Parrot-security-4.4_amd64.iso` (downloaded Dec 2018 so rather new, even if not exactly the same version as yours).

I tried, and it is similar enough compared to Debian, so that I could create a persistent live system with [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb) (using the default settings)

[image]

You may need the following data (typical for Debian and Debian based distros)

- user: 'user'
- password: 'live'

---

You can install mkusb and make persistent live systems in Ubuntu and Debian and re-spins that are similar to these linux distros.

- See instructions in this link: [help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb)